# LLCs loan interest to avoid self-employment taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, self-employment

After doing some research on LLC setups and taxation, I have struck upon something I can't find an answer to.

If I make a loan to an LLC, taxed as a passthrough (multi member) to which I am a member of. What is to stop me from making the interest rate very high (or by doing lots of loans?) and in so doing making the amount that is passed through to me as wages very small, while maximizing the loan interest I receive which is not considered wages? The idea being to avoid self employment taxes.

In essence this would be even better than an S corporation. But it seems to good to be true... actually it sounds like it might be illegal. But I cant seem to find information on how the IRS prevents this type of thing.

According to http://www.taxlawforchb.com/2016/11/bifurcating-a-partner-for-self-employment-taxes-nothing-doing/ ...

> "However, it should be noted that there remain other transactions
>   involving payments from a partnership to a partner that do not
>   generate self-employment income, including interest on loans from the
>   partner to the partnership, and rental payments for the partnership’s
>   use of the partner’s property. Not only are such payments excluded
>   from the partner’s self-employment income, they also reduce the
>   partnership’s net operating income, the partner’s distributive share
>   of which is subject to self-employment tax."

Comment: That's not true according to http://www.taxlawforchb.com/2016/11/bifurcating-a-partner-for-self-employment-taxes-nothing-doing/

Comment: "However, it should be noted that there remain other transactions involving payments from a partnership to a partner that do not generate self-employment income, including interest on loans from the partner to the partnership, and rental payments for the partnership’s use of the partner’s property. Not only are such payments excluded from the partner’s self-employment income, they also reduce the partnership’s net operating income, the partner’s distributive share of which is subject to self-employment tax."

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't be subjected to self-employment tax which does seem like an interesting loophole, they do have interest rate minimums, but not stated maximums, feels wrong, but I've not dug in much yet. You should add the above quote and link to your question, imo.

Comment: The only thing I can see is running into usury laws or the IRS scrutinizing and re-classifying it as a capital investment rather than a loan.

Comment: For S-Corp, you can decide how much FICA tax you want to pay by simply picking your own salary, but the salary must be *reasonable*. I don't know of a particular rule preventing what you propose, but I wouldn't be surprised if the interest rate you pay an owner for a loan must also be *reasonable*.